# Different font height rendering in same browser but different OS

Tags: html, css, sass, typography

While creating a box decoration around text I'm facing an issue which is described well in two screenshots bellow.

The first one is the needed state rendered in Chrome on MacOS – not perfect but better.
The second one is the bad state rendered in Chrome on Windows.

[image: MacOS: This is what I need to achieve in Chrome running on Windows 10]

[image: Widnows: This is bad behavior]

I think it's caused because of different font height rendered in both operating systems.

This is the CSS I'm using to achieve the box background:

```
.is-hero-title {
  font-size: 4rem;
  letter-spacing: -0.02em;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.53;
  @-moz-document url-prefix() {
    line-height: 1.25;
  }  
  span {
    background: $white;
    color: $primary;
    -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
    -ms-box-decoration-break: clone;
    -o-box-decoration-break: clone;
    box-decoration-break: clone;
    display: inline;
    padding: 10px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried including the unit identifier for your line-height? I.e. 1.53rem